# SQL in Calculated member expression

Tags: expression, ssas, mdx, member

I need to use a value, selected from database table, in my Calculated member expression. How I can refer to objects outside the cube?

For example:
I have measure "Sales" in my Cube. And I want to create a Calculated member which will be a multiplication of "Sales" and some constant, selected from database table.

```
CALCULATE;   
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].MultiSales
 AS [Measures].[Sales] * <and here I need to add constant from database table>, 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

How I can refer to database table?
(this table in same datasource as cube)

Comment: Please give a more concrete example. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant.
The data on your calculation "must" be on the cube.
I say must in quotes because it depends on your storage mode. If you have a ROLAP storage mode the data wont actually reside on the cube. But that is a storage configuration.

If you want to use a value on your calculated member, create a measure group based on the table you have this value

Comment: Thanks, Diego. I resolved my problem by using Named Query for Fact table.